# WCF Service Reference in Visual Studio 2022 does not include project references

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2019 I was able to generate a WCF service reference that used shared classes for the WCF method parameters. As long as I added the project reference for the project that contained the shared classes BEFORE I generated the service reference, it would use the shared classes and not generate the classes in the reference.cs.

In Visual Studio 2022 I cannot achieve the same. No matter what I try, new classes will be generated in the reference file and will not use the existing classes in the project reference.

The list of referenced assemblies for the service reference in "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" does not include the project reference. The same list in VS 2019 shows the local project reference in this list.

I added the reference to the project contained in the same solution by right clicking on project, Add/Project Reference, select check box of the shared library.
I then added the Service Reference by right clicking on project, Add/Connected Service, WCF Web Service, add the net.tcp:://localhost of my WCF server to the URI, change service name, press Next (notice my shared project in not in list of referenced assemblies like in is in VS 2019), press Next, press Finish.
Expected my generated code on the reference.cs to used the shared library classes in the WCF methods as it does in VS 2019. However it generates the code for the classes.

Here is an example of the generated interface in VS 2019 where the classes in the shared library project is used in the generated methods:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ExampleService.IExampleImportService")]
public interface IExampleImportService {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IExampleImportService/GetExamples", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IExampleImportService/GetExamplesResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SharedLibrary.ExampleInfo[]> GetExamplesAsync();
    
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IExampleImportService/AddNewExample", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IExampleImportService/AddNewExampleResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<uint> AddNewExampleAsync(SharedLibrary.ExampleInfo example);
```

Here is the same generated interface from VS 2022 where it is using generated classes in the methods:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ExampleService.IExampleImportService")]
public interface IExampleImportService
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IExampleImportService/GetExamples", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IExampleImportService/GetExamplesResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ExampleService.ExampleInfo[]> GetExamplesAsync();
     
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IExampleImportService/AddNewExample", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IExampleImportService/AddNewExampleResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<uint> AddNewExampleAsync(ExampleService.ExampleInfo example);
```

Comment: You mean that in VS 2022, references to other projects will be stored in the directory of references, whereas in 2019, references to other projects will be displayed directly in the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jiayao - The methods in the reference.cs file will have have generated classes with 2022. Whereas the reference.cs in 2019 will use the classes in the shared library and not generate classes. I have added an example in my description above.

Comment: @richrekruciak, - I think that might be the difference between 2022 and 2019. You can choose the corresponding version according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating further, the issue seems to be due to .NET(6.0) vs. .NET Framework (4.8) and not VS 2022 vs. VS 2019.

If I create a .NET Framework (4.8) application vs. a .NET (6.0) application in Visual Studio 2022, I am able to create a WCF service reference that references existing classes.

Still not clear as to why I do not see the same behavior in .NET 6.0.